# How do I validate the uniqueness of a variable on a nested document across the board in Mongoose / MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to figure out how to validate the uniqueness of a field on a nested document across the board. Say I have the following schema:

```
var Store = new Schema({
    name     : String
  , employees: [{name: string, email:string}]
});
```

Would there be anyway to ensure that the person's email was unique across all stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can prevent duplicates in this case using a unique index in MongoDb: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes.  If you try to insert an employee with an existing email address, you'll get an exception.

Comment: Ah, for whatever reason I thought I read that it would validate uniqueness within the document (so if I tried to validate uniqueness of email, it would validate the uniqueness of against all employees under store). After rereading that and checking out the comments, it appears you're right. Thanks man!